# Laptop freezes. Could be OS or laptop, don't know

Tags: linux, laptop, freeze, linux-mint, toshiba-laptop

Model: Toshiba Satellite A205-S5809

OS: Linux Mint 12

Okay, I've read quite a few posts but none of them seem to solve my problem.

Some things I've tired:

- Remove battery, unplug, hold down power button for 30 seconds.
- Plugging it into a power strip. (Seen it suggested somewhere)
- I attempted what was suggested in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/162368/toshiba-a200-laptop-running-ubuntu-hangs-freezes-when-plugged-in) post. But without luck.

I'll start by saying my  HDD is about dead, but that isn't causing this problem I believe (Maybe it is though). Here is why I think it's not the HDD. When it's not plugged in it seems to run fine. When I plug it in though it will eventually freeze completely, some times it freezes instantly, and I have to hold down the power button to switch it off. Maybe it's just Linux Mint? Because when I ran [Slax](http://www.slax.org/) on it, it seemed to work just fine but it was running from a CD (So it could be the HDD causing this, but it doesn't happen when plugged in). Any suggestions? It could be this version of Linux maybe. If it is, could someone suggest a different version to try for a Linux beginner?

Thanks a head of time

**EDIT**
I don't know if this makes a difference, but I can mess around in the bios while it's plugged in all day and it won't freeze.

Comment: have you tried running a memory test?
It Could be faulty RAM #Edit
if it's new, check that it's seated properly. It could be a little loose. Also make sure no dust has gotten into the contacts when it was being installed.

Comment: could you be more specific? I cannot see at what specific point your laptop actually refuses to work.

Comment: The RAM I installed is rather new, but that could be it. I'll try that and report back.

Comment: Memtest86+ is the best one http://www.memtest.org/

Comment: It comes with a lot of Linux distros

Comment: @EDIT I have done both of those ideas already.

Comment: @Walter It freezes while plugged in. I don't know if it's my laptop or if it's my Linux distro.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't find the comment button, so please don't count this as an answer. If you could tell us when your computer freezes up (ex. bootup, shutdown), that would help a lot.

Comment: Linux Mint is at version 17. You should probably start by using the latest version to ensure you have the latest patches for the hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Many of the Toshiba Satellite laptops and some from HP and Dell of the same time period suffer this problem. It is caused by a faulty capacitor that mucks up the power saving features. In Windows 7 you can go into the device manager and go under CPU and select 'disable' for the CPU(s) which apparently disables some of the more advanced features of the processor. I think you may have progress if you can disable the ACPI. If I recall 'ACPI=off' can be added to the grub optional parameters. I'd recommend fiddling along these lines, of trying to disable ACPI or CPU throttling (c states and p states).

Of course the true fix is to replace that capacitor.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.hecticgeek.com/2011/11/how-to-run-hdd-smart-tests-in-ubuntu-linux/) should help you find out if your HDD is dead/dying

Comment: It IS just about dead, Linux says so and scans with various software on a Hirens disk says so. However, it only freezes when plugged in. I don't see how that would have to do with the HDD failing.

Comment: I preformed a memory test with Memtest86+ No errors.

Comment: Also, if I run a version of linux like Gentoo or Arch which just use the command line it doesn't freeze when plugged in.

Answer (score 0):

If you can work in the BIOS all day, but have issues in Linux, it may be power saving features mucking up Linux.
You might be able to turn them off in the BIOS to see it it's the problem.

Comment: I thought this too, but I don't appear to have any power saving features of any kind in my bios.