# how to keep graphics memory in constant use

Tags: ubuntu, graphics-card

i'm looking for a way to keep my graphics memory always in use as if i was playing a game or something. I'm using ubuntu lucid lynx. I have intel on board mobile graphics. Also if possible i want it to not affect the other work that i'll be doing (mostly browsing, watching videos listening to music and coding). Anyway I could do it ? I just need to do it so please don't ask me why :P

Comment: I know you said don't ask, but I think it is relevant information, and useful to providing an answer. So...why?

Comment: well my laptop keeps freezing abruptly and one of the theories is that it is a graphics card issue. It doesn't freeze while playing games and freezes otherwise. I just want to test this theory. For a detailed description of the issue check out this link and the links in it. http://superuser.com/questions/162368/toshiba-a200-laptop-hangs-freezes-when-plugged-in

Comment: you can't do that. the OS decides, which parts of the RAM will be used  where, especially when processes are switched. thus, even if you upload a texture "all the time" .. the browser might throw out the texture any time. so, as @jrista already asked: what do you want to achieve in the first place?

Comment: It would be great if you could answer the question linked above in my comment. It has been annoying me for a long time now. I just need to know what is wrong :(.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how good OpenCL works on GNU/Linux, but you could try researching that route. A simple program which just takes up some ram wouldn't be too difficult to make.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to know what is wrong with your system, permanently pushing your GPU is not a solution, it is simply alleviating a symptom. I would invert your thinking, and look at the problem...the symptom, as an opportunity to figure out what is wrong. Thats what symptoms are, indications of the problem.

I am primarily a windows user so I am not certain how this may apply to linux...but windows keeps a lot of system event logging that helps zero in on issues like this. I am not sure how much system event logging that Ubuntu does...but I would dig around and see what you can find. If you don't have any logging, I would do some research, and figure out how to enable logging, particularly for your devices, but for system and software components as well. Use your system as normal, and see what information you can glean from the symptoms you are experiencing.

Basically, treat your computer as a sick patient, and diagnose the patients disease like a doctor. ;P The more insight into the disease...usually gleaned from symptoms...the more likely you are to identify the problem and find a solution.

Comment: nicely put. I completely agree. Unfortunately the logs (which are quite detailed in ubuntu) fail to show any errors. It is as if the system just suddenly stops. Everything just stops. I have described everything in detail in my earlier posts. Please look through it if you have the time and help me out. It is very weird and no one seems to have an answer other than take it to a shop. Thank you.

Comment: I would need more information about what you have tried. Generally, I take the approach of identifying the source of my symptoms. That tends to require disabling or ending as many services and applications as possible. You would need to investigate system behavior with each service or application running in as much isolation as possible, and if that does not turn up a solution, start trying combinations. It may be that some service is heating up your system, but when you utilize the GPU, you may be getting additional cooling from a fan that is turned off when the GPU is not in use.

Comment: here http://superuser.com/questions/150056/ubuntu-windows-suddenly-freezes
http://laptopforums.toshiba.com/t5/Batteries-and-Power/Toshiba-Satellite-A205-S4617-freezes-then-lines-appear/td-p/62870